# How do I actually run an Android virtual device on AMD after installing HyperV/HVPX for flutter?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-virtual-device, haxm

Honestly it's ridiculous that this isn't documented better and it's just assumed everyone is going to be running Intel processors.

I have IntelliJ installed, and I'm trying to run an Android Virtual Device so that I can start learning development with Dart/Flutter.

The Java and Android SDKs are properly configured in my project. The only issue is that I can't get a damn emulator to run because IntelliJ keeps complaining about not having HAXM installed, despite the fact that I can't even install it on this machine because it's not an Intel processor.

I have enabled both HyperV and HVPX from within the Windows Features dialog. I have restarted. However when I go into the AVD manager in IntelliJ and attempt to create a new device I still get the **HAXM is not installed** message.

I have created a Pixel XL device, with Android API 29 (Q), a CPU/ABI of x86 and a target of Android 10.0. However when I try to run this all I get is a popup saying **Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD. HAXM is not installed.**

I do not want to use HAXM, I cannot use HAXM. I want to run this emulator through IntelliJ on my AMD processor. How do I do this?

Comment: Given that [HAXM is enabled for AMD processors](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html), you can at least mention CPU model, PC model, version of Windows, as well check that you aren't running any other VM at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. This solved the issue for me. [Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/10/android-emulator-hypervisor-driver-for.html). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should try the following steps:

1. Go to `sdk manager`
2. install `android hypervisor` driver for `AMD` processor,
3. restart `intelliJ`.

NOTE that HAXM is only for machines running on intel processors.